# I am unable to call multiple macros using one "master" macro

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a sub that will call all of my macros. Eventually I will also build this into a button for the worksheet but for now I just want it to run them all.

I'm currently getting the error:

> "sub or function not defined"

Below is the code:

```
Sub RunAll()
    Call PECcalcFinal
    Call CategroySort
    Call FormSort
    Call LabSort
    Call MaterialSort
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `CategroySort` should be `CategorySort`?

Comment: Are they declared as Public or Private?

Comment: `Option Explicit` at the top of the module?

Comment: @Rory Thanks :) Obviously need more coffefe

Comment: `Copy` and `Paste` is your friend ;)

Comment: @ManishChristian no. `Option Explicit` is your friend.

Comment: `Call` is superfluous and can be removed BTW

Comment: @Mat'sMug, yeah that one too.

Comment: @Mat'sMug and @vacip I always recommend to use `Option Explicit` too. But in this special case it helps nothing in my opinion. Or can you explain how this helps? Excel throws an exception "*Sub or function not defined*" whether you use `Option Explicit` or not. Doesn't change anything, so this won't help in this case. But still recommended to use it anyway.

Comment: @Peh correct. OP's friend is actually Ctrl+Space / autocomplete ;-)

Comment: if you did the question correctly, and included the line that the failure occurs, then you probably would have seen the typo, and not posted the question at all.

Comment: Tip:  define your variables  and subs as you do, with a mix of upper and lower case `CategorySort`  ...... when you type the variable name, in an instruction line, use all lower case `call categorysort`  .... the VBA ide will correct the variable name .... if you do not see upper case characters "pop up" then you have a typo    ... bottom line .. use uppercase characters only in `dim` statements